# parentNode returns a window object in Firefox but a div object in Chrome

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, webkit, greasemonkey

Here is some example code:

```
frames = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
parent = frames[0].parentNode;
parent.removeChild(frames[0]);
```

Works in Chrome/Webkit as a userscript.  The iframe disappears.
However, in Firefox, I will get an exception that parent has no function "removeChild" and that parent is OBJ Window.

Why?  How do I work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `frames` a global variable? If so you are running up against [`window.frames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.frames) which contains references to all of the frames on the page.

Rename the variable to something else and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Yep.  It wasn't frames, though.  It was "parent".

Thanks.

Comment: LOL, I missed parent. That one would definitely do it.

Comment: I was in a hurry. :P
Thanks again.